# How do you solve quadratic congruences with unknown modulo using Chinese Remainder Method and Hensel's Lemma

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, hensels-lemma

Show that for all positive integers $n$, the following congruence has solutions:
$$(x^2-2)(x^2+7)(x^2+14) \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$
I need to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem and Hensel’s Lemma.
So far I have shown that using for all primes where $p$ does not equal $7$ or $2$ we have $(2/p)$, $(-7/p)$, $(-14/p) = 1$, however I'm not sure how to use the Chinese remainder theorem. I understand you would need to factorise and complete the square usually but not sure how to solve this question. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You're nearly there!! By CRT if $(a,b) = 1$ then $f(x)$ has a root mod $ab$ if and only if $f(x)$ has a root mod $a$ and mod $b$ (just using the ring isomorphism). So you have showed that $f$ has a root modulo $p$ for all $p \ne 2, 7$, hence a solution mod $n$ for each $n = p_1...p_r$ for $p_i$ distinct not $2$ or $7$. The key now is to use hensel to lift mod $p$ solutions to mod $p^r$ solutions for each $r$ (and deal with the edge cases $2^r, 7^r$ (hint : for $2$ look mod $8$, for $7$, $2$ is a square...) then lift again)

Comment: $x^2=100=14\times 7+2=15\times 7-7=16\times 7-14$. $(10+7t)^2$ can be general form of solution.